# Voronoi diagram, Delaunay triangulation - data structures

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, delaunay, voronoi

I want to compute Voronoi and its dual, Delaunay triangulation. I am using Watson Bowyer algorithm. My goal afterwards is to compute alpha-shapes (concave hulls). So I will need to rapidly access the voronoi cell for a given point, the neighbors...

Which data structures did you use for your Voronoi/Delaunay algorithm? I have thought of using a disjoint set data structure with union-find operations, so that I can 'bind' to one parent, the point p in original data set, the set of point in Vp. However, one point in Voronoi diagram 'belongs' to several Voronoi cells.

What is your advice, or could you hint at some good reference?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at the half-edge data structure:

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml

Half-edge data structure is used in many applications and frameworks. One implementation of it is found in the GEL framework:

http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/projects/GEL/

Comment: Thanks! are there some simplier alternatives than data structure storing at the same time face, next edge, next vertex?

Comment: Do you know some Python implementation of this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any simpler solutions. Nor do I know any Python implementation, but the code should be fairly easy to port to Python.

Comment: If you want to use something already working, the [cgal-bindings](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/) project is providing a python wrapper around the Alpha-shape implementation of [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org).